# Inserting text having single quote in sqlite database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into sqlite database in python. Now when I have a single quote in my variable

```
data = "This is my apple's seed."
cursor.execute("insert into tableName (ColName) values ('%s')" %data)
```

it gives error like this:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

I know that this problem occurred because I didn't escape characters properly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into tableName (ColName) values (?)", (data,))
```

Docs encourages usage of DB-API's parameter substitution. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder
>   wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values
>   as the second argument to the cursor's `execute()` method.